# Service Unavailable Page

Tags: http-response-codes

Is it possible to display a static HTML page when a web service becomes unavailable because of uncertain reasons. For e.g., an outage caused due to power failure in its data center?

If so, can I know how to do it and where from that page will be served?

Also can we classify such an unavailability under Error 503?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you hoping to display this page? On the website which accesses the web service? If a webservice method fails just display an error?

Comment: Yes on the same website because if the url shows some other service name, it can mislead the users and lose on authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's classic 503.  You can certainly do it, but there has to be a server of some kind to serve the page.  That can be a load balancer/reverse proxy, which is a common way real sites handle such issues (along with general load issues).

You can also switch the DNS to another data center, but that takes time to propagate.

Comment: I assume that would be a fairly expensive way to display a static page?

Comment: @DaleBurrell, what specifically?  As I said, one idea would be to have a reverse proxy set up anyway.  This could be failure-tolerant (handle servers crashing/losing power).  Then, if all the web service servers drop out, it can start redirecting all requests to a static server.  You could use any efficient static server for this.

Comment: I'm thinking if one doesn't already have such a setup it would be a bit of a step up. And I guess the only point is to avoid the consuming web site from having to timeout?

Comment: @Dale, agreed, but if the website is important enough to need/want this last chance static fallback, it's probably important enough to need basic load balancing.  Like any error, it's about making the situation clear to the client.

Answer (score 0):

yes because 
`Error 503: Service Unavailable means; the server took too long to answer and the connection timed out.`